# How to copy Input Calendar value into searchbox or filter the table through calendar value, in Asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, datatable, calendar, search-box

Visual Studio 2019, SQL Server 2014, Asp.net core 5.0 
I'm inserting data on a Create page, which is divided into two parts : Input(30%) and Table(70%). 
The table lists all the data already inserted
and through a searchbox i can look and filter the data.
**What i want to do is to:**
a. Click on the calendar and the calendar filters the table directly.
Or
b.Click on the calendar and the calendar inserts the date into the searchbox which will filter the table.
This way if i have to insert some data, i can already see if it exists something for that date.

Comment: Hi @blackwolf511,could you please share how do you design the calendar?More code would be helpful.

Comment: The calendar is the default type, on asp.net core  <input type="date" />   ...here is the link on mega:     https://mega.nz/file/YJ1xECLa#IiKpI4yT0aldK6oGmrFZK6wd1h59DeRpgauBnLWYtVk

Comment: I have found a half solution, which copies the date into the searchbox but doesnt filter it. To make it work, after the date is displayed into the searcbox, i have to click on it and then press Enter.   <input class="form-control" type="date"
        id="dateX" name="dateX" onchange="SearchX();" onkeyup="SearchX();" onkeydown="SearchX();" autofocus />  <input type="search" id="search" class="search" />    <script>   function SearchX() {   var readdate = document.getElementById("dateX").value;  document.getElementById("search").value = readdate.split('-').reverse().join('/');
    }</script>